# Dynamic Login Formatting

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamic

My goal for this function is to have

Username: input

password: input

repeat password: input

but the formatting right now is:

username:

input

password:

input

repeat password:

input

How would I go about fixing this formatting? I believe it has to do with the way I am appending them into the form area but I can't seem to resolve this issue. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
function addLogin(){
var f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute('method', "post");
f.setAttribute('action', "project6.php");

var userTxt = document.createElement("p");
userTxt.innerHTML ="Username: ";
var username = document.createElement("input");
username.setAttribute('type', "text");
username.setAttribute('name', "username");

var passOneTxt = document.createElement("p");
passOneTxt.innerHTML = "Password: ";
var passOne = document.createElement("input");
passOne.setAttribute('type', "text");
passOne.setAttribute('name', "passOne");

var passTwoTxt = document.createElement("p");
passTwoTxt.innerHTML = "Repeat Password: ";
var passTwo = document.createElement("input");
passTwo.setAttribute('type', "text");
passTwo.setAttribute('name', "passTwo");

f.appendChild(userTxt);
f.appendChild(username);
f.appendChild(passOneTxt);
f.appendChild(passOne);
f.appendChild(passTwoTxt);
f.appendChild(passTwo);

var area = $("formarea");
area.appendChild(f);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User the paragraphs tags as a container and add the label and input as children to that paragraph.

```
var userP = document.createElement("p")
var userTxt = document.createElement("span");
userTxt.innerHTML ="Username: ";
var username = document.createElement("input");
username.setAttribute('type', "text");
username.setAttribute('name', "username");
userP.appendChild(userTxt);
userP.appendChild(username);

f.appendChild(userP)
```